# msf4j request threws an exception Error in http connector listener

Tags: wso2, wso2-msf4j

I have created a microservice using msf4j framework and configured the postgres database using Hibernate jpa and started the server.

I could able to do post/get operation successfully but in the backend getting this below error. Can anyone guide me to resolve this.

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        user0_.firstName as firstNam2_0_0_,
        user0_.lastName as lastName3_0_0_ 
    from
        USER_DETAIL user0_ 
    where
        user0_.id=?
2019-05-25 07:56:36 ERROR MSF4JHttpConnectorListener:268 - Error in http connector listener
org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contract.ServerConnectorException: Remote client closed the connection before initiating inbound request
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.listener.SourceHandler.notifyErrorListenerAtConnectedState(SourceHandler.java:238)
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.listener.SourceHandler.channelInactive(SourceHandler.java:165)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:277)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.common.BackPressureHandler.channelInactive(BackPressureHandler.java:45)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.channelInactive(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:143)
    ~~~
```